# Why does std::unordered_set not take CComBSTR type as a key?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, com, atl

When I try to use `std::unordered_set<CComBSTR>` (or `std::unordered_set<CAdapt<CComBSTR>>`), I get the error

```
c:\apps\vs2017pro\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\unordered_set(105) : error C2280 : 'std::hash<_Kty>::hash(const std::hash<_Kty> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
with
[
    _Kty = ATL::CComBSTR
]
```

But `std::set<CComBSTR>` (or `std::set<CAdapt<CComBSTR>>`) is fine. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

<s>What can I do to still achieve the O(1) time complexity for search?</s> (Of course, we can use a custom hash function to achieve O(1) time complexity for search.)

The minimal reproducible example is given as below.

```
#include "atlbase.h" 
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    //std::unordered_set<CComBSTR> s;    // compile error
    //std::unordered_set<CAdapt<CComBSTR>> s;    // compile error

    //std::set<CComBSTR> s;    // ok
    //std::set<CAdapt<CComBSTR>> s;    // ok

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT (06/02/2019):**

I understood the error that there was no hash function for `CComBSTR` and we can create a custom one. What I meant to ask was what is the design reason for `std::set` to have a hash function but not `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: `what is the design reason for std::set to have a hash function but not std::unordered_set?`  Actually, it's the other way round.  `std_set` is implemented as a balanced tree, which means its contents are inherently sorted but insert and access times are both O(NlogN).  `std::unordered_set` is implemented as a hash table, which means both these operations are O(1).  Which you choose to use depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't know how to hash your key.  To fix this, you need to provide a custom hash function:

```
#include "atlbase.h" 
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <string>

struct HashBSTR
{
    size_t operator () (const CComBSTR &bstr)
    {
        return std::hash <std::wstring> () (bstr.m_str);
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::unordered_set <CComBSTR, HashBSTR> s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I understood what the error meant and how to fix. Please see my edit.